# I can't log into a mysql service which is built on Docker/Apine due to wrong password, what can I do?

Tags: mysql, docker, alpine

I run a docker/alpine based mysql instance for many days, today I want to log into it, but I get the following error:

```
bash-4.4# mysql -uroot -h 172.19.0.1 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 
'root'@'172.19.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

I don't know it is because I used the wrong password or any other causes, what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure `root` has the authorization to login out of localhost (mysql privileges are given host by host) ? What happens if you login directly inside the container (i.e. `docker exec -it your_container_name mysql -u root -p`) ?

Comment: the same "Access denied for user"

Comment: Well then it looks like you don't know your password.... You need to reset it.  There is an [explanation in this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-change-and-recover-a-mysql-root-password/) (out of the numerous ones on the subject). Basically you need to mount your existing db, start it with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`, then connect to the db, change the root password and finally restart the database normally.